# Can we add a little more space on the User Activity page? (Graphical glitch)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, recent-activity

After doing an edit, where the entry shows up on the activity page, the underline from the link is partly hidden by the highlighted section which says what the edit was. Screenshot:

[image]

Could we add a couple more pixels of space between the name of the question and the edit so it doesn't obscure the underline which just looks a little un-tidy?

Comment: Could you provide browser and version information?

Answer (score 1):

Either this is a browser issue or this is fixed because it does not happen for me, look for example at https://askubuntu.com/users/19490/n-n?tab=activity&sort=revisions.